# Get ALL items in a SelectList within ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, controller, selectlist

Is there a way to post all items in a SelectList (multiselect) to the method of a controller? By default when I use a SelectList it will only post the selected items to the Form.

I have a couple of MultiSelect controls on a View. Using jQuery the user can move items from ListBox1 to ListBox2 and vice versa. When the form is posted I want to be able to determine all items that ended up in ListBox1. However when I evaluate Form["ListBox1"] in my controller it will only provide me a comma delimited list of the SELECTED values - but I want ALL items in ListBox1. Not just the selected ones.

How can I get the View to post ALL items in ListBox1 and not just the selected ones?

Comment: All the answers assume your clients have js enabled. Be careful with this and know you user base well before using a js enabled only solution

Comment: If the clients have no js enabled, they are unable to move items from one listbox to another!

Comment: Why, you can implement this using normal post requests!!

Comment: JQuery should be used to enhance the experience. Not drive it 100%

Comment: Thanks for the comments tsk and redsquare. 

If I want to allow the user to move items between listboxes on the client side without postbacks then I have to make the unfortunate choice of having jQuery drive the experience 100%. I was hoping there would be another way because I do subscribe to the notion that jQuery should only enhance experience. I am going to make an exception in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use javascript to **select** all the ListBox options then all of them will be send to your controller.

Please find this [link](http://www.nabble.com/jQuery-select-all-vs-conventional-javascript-td20596367s27240.html) to be helpfull.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jQuery to move items from one to the other, why not user jQuery to fill a hidden form field with all the items from ListBox1?

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice jquery plugin you could use:

http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/

You can select options using regular expressions, to just select everything